# mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/log': Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: linux, docker, google-cloud-platform, cron, google-cloud-run

My application is deployed in cloud run service. It was working fine until i added cronjob script into my entrypoint file. the strange thing is it is working fine when i run the container into my local machine and compute engine but when I deploy the same service in cloud run the container get exited with above error.
i have added the screenshot of my logs as well and the entrypoint file.
Cloud run logs
[image: cloud run Logs]

Comment: And I have not added any volumes, so couldn't get the point that Why transport endpoint is not connected

Comment: Could you please share the docker file you are working while you get this error.